# In a BIBD, why is it the case that $r>\lambda$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Given a BIBD $(v,b,r,k,\lambda)$, I'm trying understand the proof of Fisher's inequality, but I'm stuck at the step where the assertion $r>\lambda$ is made. But why? The only pieces of information I have is $vr=bk$ and $\lambda(v-1)=r(k-1)$.

Comment: There is a tsunami of acronyms: please give "in extenso" what is BIBD... ?

Comment: BIBD is a balanced incomplete block design, where $v$ number of points, $b$ is the number of blocks, $r$ is the number of blocks containing any given point, $k$ is the number of points contained in each block, $\lambda$ is the number of blocks containing each pair of points.

Comment: A BIBD is a balanced incomplete block design.  This may be one of those terms in math which are about,as cryptic as their acronym.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had seen this acronym, but I was unable to find back its meaning.

Comment: Have you seen:  theoremoftheday.org/Statistics/Fisher/TotDFisher.pdf ?

Comment: It doesn't really prove $r>\lambda$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every point is in precisely $r$ blocks.

Every pair of distinct points is in precisely $\lambda$ blocks.

Since $\{p,q\}\subset S\implies p\in S$, it is unavoidable that $r\ge\lambda$.

Now suppose that $r=\lambda$. Then for any point $p$, occurring in $r$ blocks, every pair of points $\{p,q\}$ must appear in all $r$ blocks; so every other point uses the same $r$ blocks, and $b=r$ and $v=k$, making all blocks complete and the design degenerate.